# How do I write a boolean remove method for an OrderedList class

Tags: java, eclipse, doubly-linked-list

Im kind of stumped right now, I need to write the remove method for an OrderedList class and this is what I have so far

```
boolean remove(E obj) {
    ListIterator<E> iter = theList.listIterator();

    while (iter.hasNext()){
        if (obj.compareTo(iter.next()) == 0) {

        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

I understand how the algorithm works by making the next item equal the previous but I just am not sure how to implement it.

Comment: Whats the underlying data structure you are using to store the data?  you tagged it as doubly-linked-list... do you have nodes holding the previous/value/next information?

Comment: Im using java.util.LinkedList<E>

Comment: oh why not just call the remove on it.

Comment: Michael, if either Charles or Toms answers helped you - you should "accept" the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html

```
boolean remove(Object o)
Removes the first occurrence of the specified element from this list, if it is present.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the iterator, `iter.remove();`.